# Need pointers on my first Windows program

Tags: windows, networking, low-level

I'm a Unix programmer and I need to write a (hopefully simple) program for Windows that does the following:

(1) Installs from a USB drive
(2) Somehow integrates with the OS at a low-level in such a way that it can filter/shape all network traffic in/out of the machine (a la IPSec)

I can write in C, asm, Python, Java, but I have no idea about Windows' methods for doing this sort of thing, nor where to start learning.  (I could easily do the above with Linux using a kernel module.)

Comment: Far from simple as a rule, have a look at the [Wireshark codebase](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/).

Comment: Your best bet of achieving this would be C++/CLI or C#

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks for the pointer, but my understanding is that Wireshark is based on WinPCap which is a sniffer, not a filter (ie, it cannot shape traffic, only collect statistics and log traffic).  I will edit my question to make it clearer what my needs are.

Comment: In which case, I would suggest having a look at the [PeerBlock code](http://www.peerblock.com/development/compiling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You going to need to come up to speed on how to write an [NDIS filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Kernel-mode work is usually performed using the Microsoft C compiler and the remote kernel debugger WinDbg.